# Select all objects with a specified value

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Working in jQuery or plain javascript

If i have an array of objects like so:

```
    [
    {"company":"acme", "Employees":10, "location":"Cork"}, 
    {"company":"foo", "Employees":50, "location":"Limerick"},
    {"company":"bar", "Employees":10, "location":"Dublin"}
    {"company":"zanzo", "Employees":23, "location":"Dublin"}
    ]
```

is there a convenient way for me to query this data?

e.g. get all companies with over 20 employess, or get all companies located in Dublin

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function. For example:

```
var companiesWithOver20Employees = $.grep(companies, function(company, index) {
    return company.Employees > 10;
});
```

or:

```
var companiesInDublin = $.grep(companies, function(company, index) {
    return company.location == 'Dublin';
});
```